# How to dedicate user to single session host server

Tags: rds

In my environment, I've 10 session host servers and 400 users that'll be going to connect. I have a requirement of 10 users should have different session host servers at all the time. and the rest of 390 users can have any session host servers out of 10session hosts. Is there any way of dedicating these users a separate host server when they RDP\RDWeb access. Kindly share your views and suggestion. I sincerely appreciate your thoughts and answers

FYI RDS setup has done on Windows server 2012 Gateways servers 2 Broker 1 Session host servers 10.

RDS is in working state not in production though

Comment: no one knows the answer?